# ffmpeg does not produce smooth videos from mkv h265

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, x264, h.265

It's kind of subjective, but I'm not able to produce 100% smooth videos with ffmpeg.
As input I use https://www.libde265.org/hevc-bitstreams/tos-1720x720-cfg01.mkv as a example.This is a h264 mkv video which is running really badly with my vlc player on my win7 laptop.Converting it to a h264 video let it play much better, but it still appears not to be 100% smooth. Especialy in Vegas 9 it even hangs like once a second.

Other h264 videos even with 1080p or bigger run perfect with vlc and much better with Vegas, so it is not my laptop.

its seems that there can be a lot of differences between h264 and h264??
what could i try to make them more smooth?

I'm using following command to convert the video:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i INPUT_FILE -ac 2 -vf scale=trunc\\(oh*a/2\\)*2:480 -c:v libx264 -sn -dn -map_metadata -1 -map_chapters -1 -profile:v high -level:v 4.0 -pix_fmt yuv420p OUTPUT_FILE
```

Comment: Are you sure your syntax is correct here: `\\(oh*a/2\\)*2`?

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg and check. Older versions may not be reordering B-frames correctly.

Comment: @video.baba I actually copied this from a quoted statement and forget to remove the second \

Comment: So I updated to the newest ffmpeg version (20181212 windows),which is not so much newer than my last but it doesn't change anything.Even the output filesize is the same.

Comment: If you're re-encoding this so it works better in your editor then you should use a different format than H.264. Use a(n intra frame) lossless compressed intermediate format. Not sure what Vegas supports, but if it supports VFW then you can install UT Video and use that.

Comment: No I need it to run it smooth, it will not be re-encoded.Other h264 videos run perfectly

Comment: You should move this Question to the Video section.